# Unity 2D Sprite Bending between Hinge Joints

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, image

I've created a tentacle that consists of multiple game objects, each attached to eachother using HingeJoint2D's. Gameplay wise this multiple segmented approach is great because I can use Unity's built-in physics, but it doesn't look very good art wise.
[image]

Is it possible to 'bend' 2D sprites, so the tentacle segments look like they're attached to eachother? Or perhaps take a single image and bend it using splines of some sort?

I would prefer to keep using multiple game objects to represent the tentacle.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Unity, so some of my suggestion could be irrelevant.

1. You could try and compose a sprite based on the vertices of the GameObjects that you bend. This would help hide the 'chain' that is behind.
   In the image bellow, in black is your original "chain". You take some precise location on it and you make out of it a new "continuous chain", drawn in red. 
   [image]
2. Instead of having long segments, you could try to alleviate the issue by using circle shapes. You'd have to reduce the angle of freedom for your joints, but since you'll have more, you'll end up with the same result.  
   [image]
3. The third option I see is instead of using rectangle sprites, try and make 'capsule' sprites: a rectangle with half circle on each end. This would still have "angle-ish" joints, but at least, you won't see the rectangle separations. 
   [image]

In any case, you'll need to tweak your sprites graphics.

Comment: Great in-depth answer! The capsule approach is certainly the easiest. I'll give it a shot and see how it looks.